# What's the best FQL query to get URLs that a particuler user likes within my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

As I described in title, I'm looking for the way to retrieve a list of URLs that a current user likes within my application.

Each of my application web page uses OGP and has app_id, so page's URL should be related to my application. What I have in my mind is to get a list of URLs or object ids of my web pages with a subquery and then get the URLs that a user likes from the list. Or there might be some smarter ways to solve this...

Any solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no solution for this. You can't get access to who has liked what even on the URLs from your own site/app.

Tons of developers have been looking for such a feature, but there's no solution as of yet. The only thing facebook makes available is the number of likes on URLs.

Cheers,
-Roozbeh

Comment: Yep. AFAIK Roozbeh is right. You can get the like count, but not the list. A list of user ids is available for links, photos, photo albums, etc. but not URLs.

Comment: one thing you can do is to track the lickes directly using the javascript callback edge.create / edge.remove and fire an ajax request to your database. but you can never be sure to catch everything.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I thought about that too. But, as you said, it's not sure we can get all 'like' correct and I was afraid of having some data missing. I just gave up working on this.